# Reusability of tests in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I would like to run some automated tests for testing a web application in which process workflows are handled.

For the interfacing with the application itself I've written already a Page Object Model which makes use of Selenium WebDriver in order to interact with the several components of the application.

And now I'm about to write a number of tests which should allow me to run a number of automated tests for that particular application. And as a test framework I would like to use TestNG.

But because of the fact that the application under test is a workflow application, I discovered that I always need to work me through a certain part of the process flow first in order to do a test afterwards.

Example testcase 1: Add an activity to certain task in a dossier

1. Login to application
2. Open dossier x
3. Open task y within dossier x
4. Add activity z to task y within dossier x

Example testcase 2: Add a planning for a certain activity on a task in a dossier

1. Login to application
2. Open dossier x
3. Open task y within dossier x
4. Add activity z to task y within dossier x
5. Add the planning for activity z

So as you can see from the examples above, I always need to work myself through a certain amount of similar steps before I can do the actual test.

As a starting point for myself I started writing TestNG classes. One for testcase 1 and a second one for testcase 2. Then, within each test class I have implemented a number of test methods which correspond to the test steps.

See example code below for testcase 1:

```
public class Test_Add_Activity_To_Task_In_Dossier extends BaseTestWeb {

private Dossier d;
private Task t;

@Test
public void login() {
    System.out.println("Test step: login");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "login")
public void open_dossier() {
    System.out.println("Test step: open dossier");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "open_dossier")
public void open_task() {
    System.out.println("Test step: open task");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "open_task")
public void add_activity() {
    System.out.println("Test step: add activity");
}
```

}

And here the example code for testcase 2:

```
public class Test_Add_Planning_For_Activity_To_Task_In_Dossier extends BaseTestWeb {

private Dossier d;
private Task t;

@Test
public void login() {
    System.out.println("Test step: login");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "login")
public void open_dossier() {
    System.out.println("Test step: open dossier");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "open_dossier")
public void open_task() {
    System.out.println("Test step: open task");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "open_task")
public void add_activity() {
    System.out.println("Test step: add activity");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "add_activity")
public void add_planning() {
    System.out.println("Test step: add planning");
}
```

}

So as you can notice already this kind of structuring the tests is not maintainable as the amount of testcases to be written grows because I'm now always repeating the same steps first before I arrive to the actual test to be done...

Therefore I would like to ask the community here upon how it would be possible to make everything more reusable and avoid the writing of repeated steps over and over in every single testcase

All ideas are more than welcome!!

Comment: Before providing answer I want to ask what you want? you are doing duplicate stuff for Login > Open dossier >  open task > add activity. you want to make it one time, Am i correct?

Comment: In fact, due to the nature of the application (i.e. process workflow management tool), I always need to work myself one step further in the complete flow in order to do some further testing on the application itself. Now in most of the cases, in order to come to that 'one step further' I'll need to execute similar steps in each testcase again... This leads to a lot of duplication in code if I keep on following my current approach. Therefore I would like to find out here if there exists some better ways in implementing the testcases.

Comment: I have added answer. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to remove repeated stuff that you are doing before each test case like

```
Login to application
Open dossier x
Open task y within dossier x
```

You can use `@BeforeMethod` so it will do these prerequisites task (basically you can keep common task that need before every test) before each test case.

```
   @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp()
    {           
     login();   
     open_dossier();
     open_task();
    }
```

**Test case - 1**

```
@Test
     public void testAddActivity() 
{
add_activity();
}
```

**Test case - 2**

```
@Test
     public void testAddPlanning() 
{
add_planning()
}
```

Comment: Hi! In your proposed approach, where would you put the implementation of the methods you'll be calling from within the method setUp()? I.e. would you place them somewhere in a parent class from which each individual testclass should extend from then?

Comment: Yes. Standard practice says to make "BaseTest" class and keep setup method there. All your test class should extends  "BaseTest" class. If you keep this any of test class it will work too as Testng always look for annotation start from @before

Comment: @HansMens You can accept it as answer if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have had a simillar environment where i needed to have accounts in the right state to start my tests. I made a pacakage named accelerators and opend some process based classes to move the accounts from process to process to get them in the right state. My advice is not to put the @Test annotation above the methods of the accelerators. But to call those accelerator classes and methods inside your actual tests.

If you have more questions feel free to ask them.

So i edited my answer because i couldnt post a long comment lol im fairly new here.

@Hans Mens So what i did is I created the class and methods as how the processes are as accelerators. And inside the @BeforeTest annotation i invoked all accelerator classes i use in my tests. THen i extended my test method classes from the class where the @BeforeTest annotation is.That way i can use all the objects i invoked in the @BeforeTest without invoking them in the test classes so that my test scripts are clean.

Comment: So if I understand things right, your so called accelerator classes and methods are some kind of helpers which you use in order to bring some item under test into the right state before you're about to start your actual tests on it? Did you develop those helpers as static classes / methods?

Comment: And an additional question... In order to bring the application / environment to the right state before you were able to execute the intended tests, did you perform the calls to those accelerator methods from within a method out of your test class annotated with @BeforeTest ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you are using page object model. so i assume you might have written object repositories and its operation for every page by creating a separate class.
      So while writing the test just call those methods from the POM class. For example in your case:

test case 1:

```
public class Test_Add_Activity_To_Task_In_Dossier extends BaseTestWeb {@Test
    public void add_activity() {

        //To call below methods , please create object of the classes they belong to .

        login();
        open_dossier();
        open_task();

        System.out.println("Test step: add activity");
    }
}
```

Test case 2:

```
public class Test_Add_Planning_For_Activity_To_Task_In_Dossier extends BaseTestWeb {
    @Test
    public void add_planning() {

        //To call below methods , please create object of the classes they belong to .

        login();
        open_dossier();
        open_task();
        System.out.println("Test step: add planning");
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.